# Menu de opciones usando Python

Tags: python, excepciones

Debo crear un menu donde pueda loguearme, asi que quiero validar todas las posibles opciones, osea que no me entre nada q no sea un numero entero dentro del rango de opciones. El problema es q no descubro todavia como hacer q mi bucle de funciones se ejecute indefinidamente hasta q se cumpla la condicion de recibir un numero valido, el programa simplemente se detiene luego de dos intentos fallidos metiendo una letra o algo asi.
Pd: El menu está en Esperanto.
Este es el codigo:

```
    def opciones():
    print('''
    Havablaj agadoj:
    1- Ensaluti
    2- Registri
    3- Eliri
    ''')
    centinela = int(input("Kie vi volas iri?: "))
    return centinela

def validacion(opcion):
    try:
        centinela = opcion
        while centinela < 1 or centinela > 3: 
            centinela = opciones()
        #system("cls")
    except ValueError:
        centinela = 0
        print("Erare, enmetu nombron kio estas en la opcia rango")
        while centinela != 1 or centinela !=2 or centinela !=3: 
            centinela = opciones()
    return centinela
    
    centinela = validacion(0)
    
    #Acciones
    if centinela == 1:
        print("Eks ensaluti")
    elif centinela == 2:
        print("Registri")
    elif centinela == 3:
        print("Adiaŭ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crear un menú es sencillo. No requiere convertir el dato introducido por el usuario a **int**, ya que eso te dará una capa adicional de código para poder validar esa entrada:

En la función `opciones()` solo hay que poner un `while` infinito el cual saldrá de ahí si el usuario introduce una de las opciones válidas de la lista `["1", "2", "3"]`

```
def opciones():
    print('''
    Havablaj agadoj:
    1- Ensaluti
    2- Registri
    3- Eliri
    ''')
    while True:
        centinela = input("Kie vi volas iri?: ")
        if centinela in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            return centinela
        print("[!] Opcion no valida, reintente\n")

def acciones(centinela):
    if centinela == "1":
        print("Eks ensaluti")
    elif centinela == "2":
        print("Registri")
    elif centinela == "3":
        print("Adiaŭ") 

opt = opciones()
acciones(opt)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es una buena forma de resolver el problema y podria haberla hecho, pero queria intentarlo usando excepciones para aprender bien como funcionan exactamente.

Answer (score -1):

Solucionado:

```
import os

def main():

    class Datos():
        opcionEscogida = -1

    def menu():
            os.system('cls')
            print("Havablaj agadoj:")
            print("1- Ensaluti")
            print("2- Registri")
            print("3- Eliri")
            while type(Datos.opcionEscogida) != int or Datos.opcionEscogida not in (1, 2, 3): 
                try:
                    Datos.opcionEscogida = int(input("Kie vi volas iri?: "))
                except:
                    pass

    def acciones():
        if Datos.opcionEscogida == 1:
            print("Eks ensaluti")
        elif Datos.opcionEscogida == 2:
            print("Registri")
        elif Datos.opcionEscogida == 3:
            print("Adiaŭ")

    menu()
    acciones()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La clase Datos contiene la variable opcionEscogida para que sea accesible desde cualquier parte del código.

Al ejecutarse el main(), primero se ejecuta menu() y a continuación acciones().

La función menu() imprime una serie de opciones y pide entrada al usuario repetidas veces hasta que esta satisfaga ciertos criterios: ser un número entero y estar en la tupla (1, 2, 3). Si se introduce algo distinto de 1, 2 o 3, se borra el texto en consola (`os.system('cls')`) y se vuelve a pedir entrada.

La función acciones() imprime un texto en función del valor de opcionEscogida, la cual se accede escribiendo `Datos.opcionEscogida`, ya que está en la clase Datos.

Comment: Gracias, aunque seria util si explicaras exactamente que hiciste xD

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen solo código tienden a considerarse de baja calidad. Por favor, explica cómo tu código resuelve la pregunta del AP. Para más información, lee [answer].

Comment: El valor esta variable: 
        opcionEscogida = -1 Es constante para toda la funcion main?

Comment: opcionEscogida se inicializa como -1. Al llamar a la función menu(), opcionEscogida toma el valor que introduzca el usuario, con la conversión de tipo a entero. Por tanto, respondiendo a tu pregunta, no es constante.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación de explicar el código. Soy nuevo en la comunidad.